# Top Level Domain of the Country were the User come from

Tags: php, geolocation, geocoding, geo

I need a php script which displays the tld of the users Country.
For example if User comes from Britain then i need the output "uk" or if he is German i need "de" for Austria "at" for American "us" and so on.

You can watch it on [wordcreator.org](http://www.wordcreator.org/woerter.php?q=flow). There should be instead of ".de" the Country TLD of the user. In the Line were is ".yourCountry", ".com", ".net", ".org" and so on.

Comment: There are exact what i need, but i need it without this big frameset. [Processwire](https://processwire.com/api/multi-language-support/multi-language-urls/) What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Wow its so easy!

```
<?php $location = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])); print_r($location) ?>
```

Installationmanual: [Here](https://www.a-coding-project.de/ratgeber/php/geolocation)